# Can't submit Data Analytics job in PowerShell Portal

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Why can't I run the Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob cmdlet in a PowerShell runbook via the Aure web portal? I get the following error message:

> Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob : The term 'Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob' is not recognized as the name of a 
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
>   that the path is correct and try again.

I'm able to run this command with no errors in the PowerShell ISE.

Can this type of command not be run in a runbook or something? Maybe I'm just not understanding PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the issue. I had to import some AzureRM.* modules via the Module Gallery on the portal.